# Columns, transforms and pixel rounding issue

Tags: css

I'm experiencing a weird issue which seems to be due to bad pixel rounding when using transforms with a percentage.

Basically, I have a column structure, and the inside of the column has a width equal to 200% of the column itself. I want to then use a transform to toggle the inside of the column to the left, to show the right side of it, by using `transform: translateX(-50%)`

You can see a simplified [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/sqmacweb/)

The issue is however, that depending on the width of the viewport (try resizing the frame), a 1 pixel whitespace is shown for some of the columns. This happens in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this?

Edit: I'm aware that I can "fix" the issue by adjusting the transform value, or the width of the items, but that's not really ideal, and I'm hoping there's a proper way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused because of transform: translate property miscalculation in browsers. Usually by changing object size, padding or margin by 1 or 2 pixels fixes this issue.

Try using `width: calc(200% + 2px);` for element with transform property.

Comment: Yeah I was playing around with that as well, but was hoping there would be a "real" (non-hacky) solution.. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: There won't be "non-hacky" solution, it's always caused by some 1px, you have to add or remove it somewhere. Doesn't matter if it's width, padding or margin.

Comment: That's to bad. I'll go with this solution then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`transform: translateX(-49%);` seems to fix it

Comment: Yeah, though that's not really what I want. In the real example the items have to exactly align to other items, so it needs to be exactly 50%..

Comment: since 1px is the problem, `translateX(50% + 1px)`